# ionic 2 inappbrowser POST form with data params

Tags: http, xmlhttprequest, http-post, ionic2, inappbrowser

I want to submit a `POST` form to an **external** url, that should open a new window with post data params using the in app browser, so how i can do this in `ionic2` ?

Answer (score 8):

you can do it like this using InAppBrowser in ionic 2;

1. Install the Inappbrowser cordova plugin

   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
2. import the Inappbrowser component

   import {InAppBrowser} from 'ionic-native';
3. create a javascript script string that we will be executing in the inappbrowser using that we will create a dynamic form on the fly and post data to the url. 
   for the we need to create an html page like redirect.html and place it in the www folder and we will open this file in the in app browser and post a form to the external url from this html file

create an html file and place it in www folder of the app
redirect.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Redirecting to the payment page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <b>
    please wait we are redirecting to the payment page....
</b>
    <form id="ts-app-payment-form-redirect"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

in the compnent do like this

```
   let options = {
        name: 'tanveer ahmad dar',
        email: 'tanveerahmaddar@example.com',
        item_id: 1234,
        reference: 1234,
        item_descr: 'description',
        item_quant: 1,
        item_valor: 50 * 100
    };

let formHtml:string = '';
for(let key in Options){
   if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       let value = result[key];
      formHtml+='<input type="hidden" value="'+value+'" id="'+key+'" name="'+key+'"/>';
   }
}

let url = "some payment gateway url"
let payScript = "var form = document.getElementById('ts-app-payment-form-redirect'); ";
payScript += "form.innerHTML = '" + formHtml + "';";
payScript += "form.action = '" + url + "';";
payScript += "form.method = 'POST';" ;
payScript += "form.submit();" ;
```

4. open the inappbrowser and execute the script by using executeScript method of inappbrowser on loadstop event

   ```
   if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
     let browser = new InAppBrowser('redirect.html', '_blank', 'location=no');
      browser.show();
      browser.on("loadstart")
      .subscribe(
         event => {
            console.log("loadstop -->",event);
            if(event.url.indexOf("some error url") > -1){
            browser.close();
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(BookingDetailPage,{
                success:false
             });
           }
         },
         err => {
           console.log("InAppBrowser loadstart Event Error: " + err);
      });
      //on url load stop
       browser.on("loadstop")
      .subscribe(
          event => {
             //here we call executeScript method of inappbrowser and pass object 
             //with attribute code and value script string which will be executed in the inappbrowser
             browser.executeScript({
                 code:payScript
              });
          console.log("loadstart -->",event);
          },
      err => {
         console.log("InAppBrowser loadstop Event Error: " + err);
      });
     //on closing the browser
      browser.on("exit")
     .subscribe(
       console.log("exit -->",event);
     },
     err => {
      console.log("InAppBrowser loadstart Event Error: " + err);
     });
   }
   ```

i have done it like this i posted the hidden form with payment details to the payment url using this method. its working smooth.
i can also check the inappbrowser url changes in loadstart and loadstop events i can clse the inappbrowser on success or failure urls

hope this helps you.. :)

Comment: well.. not working. App crashes when this page loads.

Comment: @tanveerahmaddar how do you get the parameter upon redirect from the payment gateway? The payment gateway makes a POST request to the redirect URL. Is the inAppBrowser capable of reading parameters from a POST method?

Comment: @AshikBasheer you dont have to read the parameters in inappbrowser, we are just posting form to the payment server through inappbrowser, in response we will get a new page ie payment page.